# I want to create multiple PDA accounts made with different seeds belonging to a single user/wallet. to be exact I want to initialize multiple PDA Aco

Tags: pda, account, wallet, bump, initialize

I want to create multiple PDA accounts made with different seeds belonging to a single user/wallet. to be exact I want to initialize multiple PDA Accounts with different seeds or bumps belonging to a single wallet.

!!!!Updated the post!!!!!!!

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(bumper: String)]
pub struct PuntAccount<'info> {

       #[account(init, payer = user, space = 10000,
       seeds=[bumper.as_ref(), user.key().as_ref()],bump)]
       pub punter_account: Account<'info, Punter>,


    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>, //admin
}
```

Im using https://beta.solpg.io/ and using first seed as  random and giving my public key of wallet. But error is thrown:

The program could not deserialize the given instruction.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on this? I don't understand what you need help with. Try describe the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can init multiple PDAs in the same instruction using different seeds. Is this what you are trying to do?

```
#[program]
mod init_multiple_pda {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, seeds = [b"seed_one".as_ref(), signer.key().as_ref()], bump, payer = signer, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub account_one: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
    #[account(init, seeds = [b"seed_two".as_ref(), signer.key().as_ref()], bump, payer = signer, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub account_two: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
    #[account(init, seeds = [b"seed_three".as_ref(), signer.key().as_ref()], bump, payer = signer, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub account_three: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct NewAccount {
    data: u64
}
```

https://beta.solpg.io/62ed3cd4f6273245aca4f629

Response to comment:
You can use `#[instruction(...)]` to access the instruction data and use it as a seed. For example,

```
#[program]
mod init_pda {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, input: String) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(input:String)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, seeds = [input.as_ref(), signer.key().as_ref()], bump, payer = signer, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub account_one: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct NewAccount {
    data: u64
}
```

Comment: Ok, So what your doing is that, your creating PDA's with fixed seeds, I want to create like,PDA's with dynamic seeds, e.g: replace seed_one with a variable, when passed, it should create a valid Account with a different seeds.

Comment: You can use the ```#[instruction(...)]``` attribute to access the instruction data and then use it as a seed. Edited the response above, is this what you are trying to do?